# WriteableBitmap dont let me draw a Rectangle (AccessViolationException)

Tags: c#, wpf, writablebitmap

I have a wpf UserControl that should draw a little chart. The UserControl is rendered multiple times within a grid. Unfortunately I get a AccessViolation Exception when the UserControl is visible more than once.

The AccessViolation Exception is thrown after some other drawing (only FillRectangle calls)..

This is how the code looks:

```
var bmp = BitmapFactory.New(200, 30);
using (bmp.GetBitmapContext())
{
    bmp.FillRectangle(0, 0, (int)bmp.Width , (int)bmp.Height , MyColors.WhiteSmoke);

    // .. some calculations and rectangle drawings

    bmp.FillRectangle(vX1, vY1, vX2, vY2, Colors.RosyBrown);  //<- Violation Exception
}
```

**The strange thig is:**
When I change the last line to:

```
bmp.FillRectangle(vX1, vY1, vX2, vY2, Color.FromArgb(100, Colors.RosyBrown.R, Colors.RosyBrown.G, Colors.RosyBrown.B));
```

everything works fine.

This is the first time I am using WritableBitmap. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: AFAIK, `BitmapFactory` is not WPF but Xamarin.

Comment: How do "MyColors" and "Colors" differ? (I have seen evil things being done in innocent getters)

Comment: @shadow32 MyColors.WhiteSmoke is `(Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#f5f5f5")`

Comment: @dymanoid: You are right.. I will check that.. Copied the BitmapFactory part from somewhere without checking where it comes from. It only works because a SciChart library is defining it.

Comment: @richej Can you try to explicitly check if the coordinates are within image bounds before the second call? (I don't see what else could have gone wrong...)